# React Native Navigation: Identify if component is modal

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a component that is sometimes pushed as a regular screen on top of the stack, and sometimes shown as a modal.

When a specific event occurs, I need to get rid of the component. But I don't know if it's a modal or a regular screen, so I don't know if I need to call `Navigation.pop(componentId)` or `Navigation.dismissModal(componentId)`. Is there a way to check before calling?

I tried just calling both in succession, but then one of them fails and throws an error.

I could wrap them both in a try/catch, but that seems like an anti-pattern. What is the recommended way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [command listener](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/events?id=registercommandlistener) and track when it's pushed or shown as a modal